# Update AWS Athena data & table to rename columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Today, I saw myself with a simple problem, renaming column of an Athena glue table from **old** to **new** name.

First thing, I search here and tried some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418607/aws-athena-rename-column-name), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029107/rename-column-in-athena), and many others. Unfortunately, none works, so I decided to use my knowledge and imagination.

**I'm posting this question with the intention of share, but also, with the intention to get how others did and maybe find out I *reinvented the wheel*. So please also share your way if you know how to do it.**

My setup is, a Athena JSON table partitioned by day with valuable and enormous amount of data, the infrastructure is defined and updated through Cloudformation.

**How to rename an Athena column and still keep the data?**

Comment: As no replies so far I accepted my own answer. If someday we have other I'll be happy to re visit the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explaining without all the cloudformation infrastructure.

Imagine a table containing:

- userId
- score
- otherColumns
- eventDateUtc
- dt_utc

Partitioned by dt_utc and stored using JSON format. Wee need to change the column score to deltaScore.

*Keep in mind, although I haven't tested with others format/configurations, this should apply to any configuration supported by athena as we are going to use athena algorithm to do the job for us.*

#### How to do

> if you run the cloudformation migration first, you gonna "lose" access to the dropped column.
> but you can simply rename the column back and the data appears.

Those are the steps required for rename a AWS Athena table:

1. Create a temporary table mapping the old column name to the new one:
   This can be done by use of **CREATE TABLE AS**, [read more in the aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html)
   *With this command, we use Athena engine to apply the transformation on the files of the original table for us and save at **s3://bucket_name/A_folder/temp_table_rename/**.*

```sql
CREATE TABLE "temp_table_rename"
WITH(
  format = 'JSON',
  external_location = 's3://bucket_name/A_folder/temp_table_rename/',
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['dt_utc']
)
AS
 SELECT DISTINCT
   userid,
   score as deltascore,
   otherColumns,
   eventDateUtc,
   "dt_utc"
   FROM "my_database"."original_table"
```

2. Apply the database rename by running the cloudformation with the changes or on the way you have.
   *At this point, you can even drop the original_table, and create again using the right column name.*
   *After rename, you will notice that the renamed column have no data.*
3. Remove the data of the original table by deleting it's s3 source.
4. Copy the data from the temp table source to the original table source
   *I prefer to use a aws command as, there can be thousands of files to copy*

`aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/A_folder/temp_table_rename/ s3://bucket_name/A_folder/original_table/ --recursive`

5. Restore the index of the original table
   `MSCK REPAIR TABLE "my_database"."original_table"`

done.

#### Final notes:

Using `CREATE TABLE AS` to do the transformation job, allow you to do much more than only renaming the column, for example split the data of a column into 2 new columns, or merge it to a single one.